# without using any tool, can one download any package from internet

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, software-center

Without using software Center and apt-get, How can one download
 a package like ghdl,
 gsharp.  Are there any pool in which one can find all things?

Comment: You probably have something very specific in mind that you need to write more about. If you do not want to use a pre-made installation package, you can always get the source code and compile yourself. But is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes, because of no internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the package site ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ), seach for your the package you want and hit download on the bottom of the page, e.g.: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ghdl

Comment: How can I download .deb in here ?

Comment: you click on your architecture, select a mirror on the next page and download it like usual

Answer (score 0):

You can also download these from launchpad.

1. Find that package in launchpad, ie https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxinput
2. Click on the version you wish to download at the bottom. ie `0.3.0-0ubuntu5`
3. Click on the architecture you want under builds. ie amd64
4. Click on the "built files" at the bottom.